# Drag and Drop file upload on a hidden <input type=file>

Tags: html, css

I am using this method below to hide the regular provided style and replace it with my own custom css (class="button") and now that I have done so, drag and dropping files no longer works, because the entire element is hidden.

Is there any work around to this preferably not using JavaScript?

```
<label class="button" for="file">
    <input id="file" type="file" style="display:none;">
    Browse
</label>
```

Comment: If you set an element to `hidden` then users do not have access to it in browser. so maybe [This link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) can help you

Comment: You want it to work but not display? How will I know where to drop a file?

Comment: @AllDani.com you can drag and drop files onto the <label>....

Comment: Hmm.. Please provide a fiddle so we can shed some light on this.

Comment: @EhsanT I've already read this, and it has no information related to dragging and dropping the file to upload.

Comment: OK, [this example](http://hayageek.com/drag-and-drop-file-upload-jquery/) will help you on implementing _drag n drop_

Comment: @EhsanT is there anyway to do it without JS?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but at least there is no way that I am aware of...